# return value Auto Mode XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am trying to dynamically write some xml for a webservice. I have recently been shown how to use the  FOR XML AUTO clause for my sql query, but I am not sure If one I am writing the query properly and on top of this I am not sure how to return the document values

```
using (SqlConnection oCn = new SqlConnection())
{
    oCn.ConnectionString = @"server=sql-server\cos;integrated security=SSPI;database=daas5";
    oCn.Open();

    // Create a SQL command object.
    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dd615.musicdetails WHERE artistname LIKE '%" + 
                        searchTerm + "%' OR recordname LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%' 
                        OR recordtype LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%' 
                        OR format LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'
                     FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('musicInformation') ";

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, oCn);
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? What - if anything - are you getting? Is the output just "wrong", or do you get an error - if so, what is it (in detail, please)??  Can you show us what your XML should look like in the end?

Comment: As a side note: you are aware that a sure like this is going to perform horribly bad, right? Searching for `LIKE %something%` is a perfect way to disable all indices, so you'll get a full table scan across the table 150% guaranteed.....

Comment: The SQL sever version I am using is 2005, yeah I am it was a rushed job I am going to fix it once I get it outputting XML. I don't know if it works or not at the moment since I designed the method so it returns a value and I am not sure how to take the xml from the sql statement and put it into XDocument/XmlDocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL seems fine so far - the best bet would be to use the `.ExecuteXmlReader` on your `SqlCommand` object.

```
XmlReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();
```

Once you have that, you can easily load this into an `XDocument`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(rdr);
```

or an `XmlDocument`

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(rdr);
```

so pick whichever works for you!